# Django how to override the HttpResponse 404 instead of raise exception

Tags: python, django

Currently I am implementing the custom error page for my Django Project. I have faced problem where when my project return the HttpResponse (404), the custom error page is not shown instead of, it shows the debug page.

```
#in the views.py (i define 4 functions for error 400,403,404,500) but not for Http404
from django.shortcuts import render

def page_not_found_view(request, exception):
   return render(request, 'error.html',status = 404,context = {
        'status_code' : 404,
        'message' : "The page you were looking for doesn't exist anymore.",
        'title' : "Page Not Found"
    })

def internal_server_error_view(request,  *args, **argv):

   return render(request, 'error.html',status = 500,context = {
        'status_code' : 500,
        'message' : "500 Internal Server Error.",
        'title' : "Internal Server Error"
    })

def forbidden_error_view(request, exception):

   return render(request, 'error.html',status = 403,context = {
        'status_code' : 403,
        'message' : "403 Forbidden Error.",
        'title' : "Forbidden Error"
    })

def bad_request_error_view(request, exception):

   return render(request, 'error.html',status = 400,context = {
        'status_code' : 400,
        'message' : "400 Bad Request Error.",
        'title' : "Bad Request"
    })


#in the urls.py (link 4 error handler)
hanlder400 = "gotani.views.bad_request_error_view"
handler404 = "gotani.views.page_not_found_view"
handler403 = "gotani.views.forbidden_error_view"
handler500 = "gotani.views.internal_server_error_view"
```

[image]

So my problem is, when the project return HttpResponse404, the custom error page is not shown normally. How can i override the HttpResponse (object / class), or any method how can I create a new class of HttpResponse ( and define functions inside it to override the default error template.)

Comment: try adding Debug = False in django settings

Comment: it still same however